# $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=1$ to Parametric equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, graphing-functions

After a long research, I turn to you looking for an answer to my problem consisting in converting an explicit equation to a parametric one.

As we all know $x^2+y^2=1$ is the unit circle and can be written:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\cos(t)&\\
y=\sin(t)
\end{cases}
$$ 
But I would like to turn $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=1$ to a parametric system
in order to plot it on a parametric grapher (grasshopper) with $n \to +∞$ and observe the circle tending towards a square.

After this I would also like to find the parametric system of $x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n}=1$ to move to 3D and find the cube.

Maybe we can start with $x^4+y^4=1$ and then find our way to $2n$ by mathematical induction.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  How about $x=\cos(t)^{1/n}, y=\sin(t)^{1/n}$ ?

Comment: Was about to write the same thing as @J.W.Tanner. Consider also for the case where you sum three variables, the analogy with the equation for the 3-d sphere together with J.W.Tanner's suggestion and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you take $x=\cos(t)^{1/n}$ and $y=\sin(t)^{1/n},$ then you'll have $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)=1.$

If you take $x=\cos(t)^{1/n}\cos(u)^{1/n}$, $y=\cos(t)^{1/n}\sin(u)^{1/n},$ and $z=\sin(t)^{1/n}$,

then you'll have $x^{2n}+y^{2n}+z^{2n}=1$.

Comment: Pedantry: To get the full "squircle," I believe you must take $x = {|\cos(t)|}^{1/n}\, \mathrm{sign}(\cos(t))$ and $y = {|\sin(t)|}^{1/n}\, \mathrm{sign}(\sin(t))$.

Comment: Thanks, @JohnBarber; I think you’re correct